# How to know download image completed in wp7?

Tags: download, windows-phone-7.1

Thanks in advance..

I am downloading some images from a server to my wp7 application. For that I am using the following code.

```
ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> biList;
int currentItem;

private void DownloadImages(string[] imageUriList)
{
   biList = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();
   BitmapImage bi;

   for (int i = 0; i < imageUriList.Length; i++)
   {
      bi = new BitmapImage();
      biList.Add(bi);
      bi.UriSource = new Uri(imageUriList[i], UriKind.Absolute);
      biList[i] = bi;
   }
}
```

After that I am showing these images one by one in an `<Image />` Control in my Windows Phone application.

```
<Image x:Name="imgImage" />
```

I am using following code for display images

```
private void ShowImages()
{
   imgImage.Source = biList[0];
   currentItem = 1;
}
```

And the images are changed when clicking "next" or "previous" buttons.

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if(currentItem < biList.Count)
   {
      imgImage.Source = biList[currentItem];
      currentItem += 1;
   }
}

private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if(currentItem > 1)
   {
      imgImage.Source = biList[currentItem-2];
      currentItem -= 1;
   }
}
```

When I am trying to show these images, some images are shown after some time.

How can I ensure that the images are fully downloaded?

Comment: I think there will be some `DownloadStringCompleted` event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use WebClient to download the image and once it has been successfully downloaded you can add code to the event handler as below:

```
private void GetImage()
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://website.com/image.jpg"));
    client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
}

void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //Image has been downloaded
    //Do something
}
```